# Plot points in different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a dataframe created using

```
results = df2[(df2['R'] > 100)].sort(columns='ZR', ascending=False)
```

I would like to do

```
plt.plot(results['ZR'], marker='o')
```

except I would like the points were results['I'] == foo to be in red and the points where results['I'] != foo to be in blue.

I tried

```
firstset = results.ZR[results.I.str.contains('foo')]
secondset = results.ZR[~results.I.str.contains('foo)]
plt.plot(firstset, marker='o', color='red')
plt.plot(secondset, marker='o', color='blue')
```

but this plots both halves starting from x axis 0 which is not what I need.

[image]

I would instead just like the original graph but with some of the points in red and some in blue. That is no new points and no points with changed positions. Here is the original graph.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in absence of any X parameter, `plt.show` assumes it as consecutive integers from 1. In order to find correct index using logical operations, do this:

```
firstIndex = results.index[results.I.str.contains('foo')]
secondIndex = results.index[~results.I.str.contains('foo)]
```

If your original index is complex, create a dummy pandas DataFrame for new index.

```
newDf = pd.DataFrame(range(len(results)))
firstIndex = newDf.index[results.I.str.contains('foo')]
secondIndex = newDf.index[~results.I.str.contains('foo')]
```

This is guaranteed to create two indices that are subsets of `1:230`.

Next, pass a string qulifier to `plt.plot` to specify color and marker type.

```
plt.plot(results['ZR'])
plt.plot(firstIndex, firstset, "bo")
plt.plot(secondIndex, secondset, "ro")
```

This will plot the entire underlined data using lines, with no marker for points. It will then overlay the two set points with their respective colors.

Comment: That doesn't work I am afraid. I really want exactly the second graph I showed in my question but with some of the points in red.  I don't want any of the positions of the points in the plot to change nor do I want any new points.

Comment: Sorry, one more addition. You need to specify the correct X-axis points for both `firstset` and `secondset`. In absence of that, it takes them to be consecutive points starting with 1. See the red curve in your image all shifted towards Y-axis? That is because of not passing correct X points.

Comment: firstIndex looks like [(681, 6024), (681, 6012), (679, 6009), (681, 6004), (669, 6003), (680, 6003), (679, 6008), (666, 6000), (662, 6019), (669, 6002), (662, 6017)] . Is this what you mean? You can't use it in plt.plot(firstIndex, firstset, "bo") . This is because of the way I have indexed it.  Strangely results.reset_index() doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Wait, don't you have standard `1:230` indices? If not, simply create a dummy pandas DataFrame from 1:230 and use that to index the plot. Editing my response again

Comment: results = results.reset_index() fixed it. thanks!  I look forward to your new version as well.